# Making Firestore snapshot listeners more efficient for first loading a lot of data?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, listener, service-worker, snapshot

For a heavily data driven web app, we need to run multiple Firestore snapshot listeners simultaneously. How can we improve the efficiency especially when they load a lot of data in first call? Is there any way to put them in service workers?

Answer (score 1):

The description does not make it completely clear as to your use case and requirements, but it does sound like [Firestore Data Bundles](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles.html) are inline with the optimizations you are looking for.